# How to make SQL skip record if it doesn't exist? VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite, loops

I have a loop which will go through all the Unique ID's to find existing records. If there is an ID with that number in the loop then i want it to do something, else i would like it to skip to the next number. I have a counter so i can do that part. The problem i am having is when it doesn't come across the ID it errors when trying to put nothing into a variable which makes sense. How can i get it to just move onto the next number if the number isn't there. It errors where the arrow is. My code is below:

```vb
Sub Cmd_CalculateClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    weekcount = 0

    'Calculate Bills for whole term
    Do Until counter = 9999
        valid_user = 0
        SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
        'Create SQL statement
        SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Pupil_ID FROM Pupil WHERE Pupil_ID = '" & counter & "' AND Waiting_List = 'F' "
        'Extract data
        SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()


---->   valid_user = SQLreader("Pupil_ID")



        'Clear SQL command buffer
        SQLcommand.Dispose()

        If valid_user = 0 Then
            counter = counter + 1
        Else If valid_user > 0 Then
            'Fetch Pupil attendance Days
            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
            'Create SQL statement
            SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Attendance_Monday, Attendance_Tuesday, Attendance_Wednesday, Attendance_Thursday, Attendance_Friday FROM Pupil WHERE Pupil_ID = '" & valid_user & "'"
            'Extract data
            SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

            If SQLreader("Attendance_Monday") = "T" Then
                Monday = True
                weekcount = weekcount + 1
            Else
                Monday = False
            End If

            If SQLreader("Attendance_Tuesday") = "T" Then
                Tuesday = True
                weekcount = weekcount + 1
            Else
                Tuesday = False
            End If

            If SQLreader("Attendance_Wednesday") = "T" Then
                Wednesday = True
                weekcount = weekcount + 1
            Else
                Wednesday = False
            End If

            If SQLreader("Attendance_Thursday") = "T" Then
                Thursday = True
                weekcount = weekcount + 1
            Else
                Thursday = False
            End If

            If SQLreader("Attendance_Friday") = "T" Then
                Friday = True
                weekcount = weekcount + 1
            Else
                Friday = False
            End If

            'Clear SQL command buffer
            SQLcommand.Dispose()

            'Fetch Total Sessions for that half term
            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
            'Create SQL statement
            SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Session_Monday, Session_Tuesday, Session_Wednesday, Session_Thursday, Session_Friday FROM Session"
            'Extract data
            SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

            sesmon = SQLreader("Session_Monday")
            sestue = SQLreader("Session_Tuesday")
            sesmon = SQLreader("Session_Wednesday")
            sesmon = SQLreader("Session_Thursday")
            sesmon = SQLreader("Session_Friday")

            'Clear SQL command buffer
            SQLcommand.Dispose()

            'Fetch Cost for each session
            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
            'Create SQL statement
            SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Price_Monday, Price_Tuesday, Price_Wednesday, Price_Thursday, Price_Friday FROM Price"
            'Extract data
            SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

            Cost_Monday = SQLreader("Price_Monday")
            Cost_Tuesday = SQLreader("Price_Tuesday")
            Cost_Wednesday = SQLreader("Price_Wednesday")
            Cost_Thursday = SQLreader("Price_Thursday")
            Cost_Friday = SQLreader("Price_Friday")

            'Clear SQL command buffer
            SQLcommand.Dispose()

            'Calculate Cost per day
            If Monday = True Then
                Total_Monday = sesmon * Cost_Monday
            Else
                Total_Monday = 0
            End If

            If Tuesday = True Then
                Total_Tuesday = sestue * Cost_Tuesday
            Else
                Total_Tuesday = 0
            End If

            If Wednesday = True Then
                Total_Wednesday = seswed * Cost_Wednesday
            Else
                Total_Wednesday = 0
            End If

            If Thursday = True Then
                Total_Thursday = sesthur * Cost_Thursday
            Else
                Total_Thursday = 0
            End If

            If Friday = True Then
                Total_Friday = sesfri * Cost_Friday
            Else
                Total_Friday = 0
            End If

            'Calculate week cost

            weekcost = weekcount * Cost_Monday

            'calculate term cost

            termtotal = Total_Monday + Total_Tuesday + Total_Wednesday + Total_Thursday + Total_Friday

            counter = counter + 1



        End If





    Loop






End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Just check your SQLReader after the query is executed, and make sure it has record(s) in it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense all of this to a single sql statement and **vastly** reduce your code:

```
Sub Cmd_CalculateClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim sql As String = _
   "SELECT Pupil_ID, " & _
              "CASE WHEN Attendance_Monday    = 'T' THEN p.Price_Monday    ELSE 0 END " & _
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Tuesday   = 'T' THEN p.Price_Tuesday   ELSE 0 END " & _
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Wednesday = 'T' THEN p.Price_Wednesday ELSE 0 END " & _ 
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Thursday  = 'T' THEN p.Price_Thursday  ELSE 0 END " & _
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Friday    = 'T' THEN p.Price_Friday    ELSE 0 END " & _
        "As weekTotal, " & _
              "CASE WHEN Attendance_Monday    = 'T' THEN p.Price_Monday    * Session_Monday    ELSE 0 END " & _
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Tuesday   = 'T' THEN p.Price_Tuesday   * Session_Tuesday   ELSE 0 END " & _
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Wednesday = 'T' THEN p.Price_Wednesday * Session_Wednesday ELSE 0 END " & _
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Thursday  = 'T' THEN p.Price_Thursday  * Session_Thursday  ELSE 0 END " & _
            "+ CASE WHEN Attendance_Friday    = 'T' THEN p.Price_Friday    * Session_Friday    ELSE 0 END " & _
        "As termTotal " & _ 
    "FROM Pupil p " & _
    "INNER JOIN Session s ON 1=1 " & _
    "INNER JOIN Price p ON 1=1 " & _
    "WHERE p.Waiting_List = 'F'"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
           While rdr.Read() 
               Dim pupilID   As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(rdr("Pupil_ID"))
               Dim weekTotal As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr("weekTotal"))
               Dim termTotal As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr("termTotal"))
           End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Of course I don't know what you want to do with those numbers yet, but if you're just going to write this back to the database at some location, you can even include that in the query, and never need to read the results into the VB side at all. This will *immensely* improve your performance.

Comment: As I always says but forget to follow, do not stop to the first problem, but understand the whole picture. Excellent

Answer (score 0):

```
if(SQLreader.HasRows)
{
   //....
}
```

Try this before you try getting the Pupil_ID from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to make use of ExecuteScalar and use a parameterized query

```
SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Pupil_ID FROM Pupil " & _
                         "WHERE Pupil_ID = @cnt AND Waiting_List = 'F' "
SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnt", counter.ToString)
Dim result = SQLcommand.ExecuteScalar()
if result Is Nothing then 
    Continue Do
else
    valid_user = Convert.ToInt32(result)
    .... continue with the rest of your code
```

This will help a bit in performance because ExecuteScalar could be faster than creating a instance of a SqlDataReader. Another bit of performance gain could be achieved creating the command outside the Do...Loop and updating the parameter value inside the loop

```
Sub Cmd_CalculateClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    weekcount = 0

    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
    SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Pupil_ID FROM Pupil " & _
                             "WHERE Pupil_ID = @cnt AND Waiting_List = 'F' "
    SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnt", "") 'dummy value here'

    Do Until counter = 9999
        valid_user = 0
        SQLcommand.Parameters("@cnt").Value = counter.ToString
        Dim result = SQLcommand.ExecuteScalar()
        if result Is Nothing then 
           Continue Do
        else
           valid_user = Convert.ToInt32(result)
           .... continue with the rest of your code
           .... but not destroy the command until the loop exit
```